# Issue with Importing .cypherl file in Memgraph Lab

Tags: memgraphdb

I'm a novice with Memgraph and was attempting to initialize a database by importing a `.cypherl` file in Memgraph Lab. Individual nodes are imported successfully, the relationships seem to reference nodes without any labels. When I directly execute the same queries in the Memgraph Lab's query editor, everything works perfectly. What could be the reason for this discrepancy?

Here's my code:

```
CREATE (a:Article {title: 'On Writing', author: 'Hemingway'})
CREATE (m:Magazine {title: 'Edition 1'})
CREATE (m)-[:MAGAZINE_OF]->(a)
CREATE (v0:Volume {title: 'V1', issues: 1})
CREATE (v0)-[:VOLUME_OF]->(m)
CREATE (v1:Volume {title: 'V2', issues: 2});
```

If I use Memgraph Lab's Import & Export UI to import this file I would expect to get a database with appropriately linked nodes and a schema identical to what's achieved when the queries are run directly in the query editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.cypherl` files are processed in Memgraph Lab so that each line is executed as a separate transaction. When the line `CREATE (m)-[:MAGAZINE_OF]->(a)` is executed, it ends up creating a relationship between two nodes with no labels.

To get around this issue you can structure your `.cypherl` file to first match any previously defined nodes or relationships before creating new ones:

```
CREATE (a:Article {title: 'On Writing', author: 'Hemingway'});
CREATE (m:Magazine {title: 'Edition 1'});
MATCH (m:Magazine {title: 'Edition 1'}), (a:Article {title: 'On Writing', author: 'Hemingway'}) CREATE (m)-[:MAGAZINE_OF]->(a);
MATCH (m:Magazine {title: 'Edition 1'}) CREATE (v0:Volume {title: 'V1', issues: 1})-[:VOLUME_OF]->(m)
CREATE (v1:Volume {title: 'V2', issues: 2});
```

When you import this file, you should see the expected dataset in Memgraph Lab.

If you export a `.cypherl` file from your existing dataset in Memgraph, navigate to the Import & Export tab. The exported `.cypherl` file might look somewhat different but will be structured in a way to ensure correct importing.

Before importing, the `.cypherl` file initially creates indexes and removes them in the end. Importing will first define all nodes and then execute the necessary matching based on generated ids.